# Angular ng-option: iterate over a number array for displaying content of an other array but having index chosen in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ng-options

I would like to have a dropdownlist that displays items of a string Array.
I also would like  to have as ng-model the index of the selected item in the dropdownlist.

I know I did not give the best description , so I write What I would be able to do.

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="chosenPropertyIndex"
                 ng-options="arrayProperties.PropertyNames[idx] for idx in [0,1,2,3,4,5]"
        ></select>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.chosenPropertyIndex = 0;

 $scope.arrayProperties = [
    "Property A",
    "Property B",
    "Property C",
    "Property D",
    "Property E",
    "Property F"
 ];
```

Do you see a way to do something like that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="chosenPropertyIndex" ng-options="arrayProperties.indexOf(prop) as prop for prop in arrayProperties"></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/680x5grc/

Comment: it displays well the dropddownlist but the change are not binded to ng-model. It even not trigger ng-change function more than the first time if a put it: It does  not works :(

Comment: ok  my mistake sorry , edit your answere and change just a little thing  please, It would allow me to change my vote

Comment: @VivienPipo No problem. Glad I could help.